# Is it possible that Eclipse PDE headless build use javac not jdt ( so called ecj:eclipse java compiler)?

Tags: eclipse, headless, eclipse-pde

As I know, Eclipse PDE headless build needs jdt dependency. So it means  source code is compiled with jdt - ecj - not javac.

What I want to know is how to change the compiler with javac not ecj.

Is it possible?
If so,  please let me know how.

Comment: What is the reason for this?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen , We are using SA(Static Analyzer) which works based on bytecode only from javac not ecj. Hence I want to know it's possible to change ecj to javac in headless PDE build.